# laravel route not working in linux but working in unix

Tags: php, unix, ubuntu, laravel-4

I have a route defined as below

```
Route::get("dashboard","DashBoardController@getIndex");
```

Which is working in unix (mac OSX 10.9) system but when deploy in Ubuntu server 13.04 it is not working. Laravel throws controller method not found exception.

When I change the Dash**B**oardController name to Dash**b**oardController and Route to below code

```
Route::get("dashboard","DashboardController@getIndex");
```

it works in Ubuntu as well as in unix. What  is exactly going on here? Am I missing any naming convention. Why small letter 'b' works but not the capital letter 'B'?

I am using apache server on both the machines.

Comment: Check you lower and upper case of your paths and calls to files and classes. Mac is forgiving, but Ubuntu (Linux) is not.

Comment: I changed the controller name as well as the route name to make it work. The way laravel handling this is bit different I think

Comment: There is likely some string manipulation in the background. You will get used to it very quickly. I have stumbled upon this myself and now I rather develop on Linux.

Comment: File name, dude! File name. The controller name should be the same as the file name (except, of course, byt he extention).

Comment: File Name is same dude. The problem here is Dash**b**oardController works but not Dash**B**oardController. Why a small letter b works but not capital B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HFS+ (the Mac filesystem) is usually configured to be case insensitive but case preserving. But most Linux distributions are case sensitive. So, take a look at your files names.

Also those are the cases you need to care in PHP:

**Case sensitive (both user defined and PHP defined)**

- variables
- constants
- array keys
- class properties
- class constants

**Case insensitive (both user defined and PHP defined)**

- functions
- class constructors
- class methods
- keywords and constructs (if, else, null, foreach, echo etc.)

Comment: Yes I understand that but I feel this is laraval specific. I changed the controller name as well as the route name to make it work

Comment: The only thing it is actually doing is to define that methods must be camelCase. What actually loads your classes is not really Laravel, but Composer. Look at the file vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php, your classes must be there.